# Keep column height on different viewports

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making some grid elements for a website. The demo can be [seen here](http://vouzalis.dk/panel-grid-merge.html).

There is a 2 column row. I would like they keep the same height until they reach the breakpoint 768 px. Is it incorrect to set a height on the columns?

Incase not, should i set the height on the `class="card"`?

My suggestion is not set the height like this?

```
.index-content .card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  height: 350px;

}
```

```css
.index-content a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.index-content {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /*padding: 50px 0px;*/
}

.index-content .row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.index-content a {
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.index-content .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.index-content .card h4 {
  margin: 20px;
}

.index-content .card p {
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.index-content .blue-button {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: #002E5B;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.index-content .blue-button:hover {
  background-color: #dadada;
  color: #002E5B;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .index-content .col-lg-4 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
/* Card < 768px */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    position: relative;
  }
  .card-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .card-content h4,
  .card-content p {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
  }
  .card-content a {
    float: right;
  }
  .index-content .card h4,
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 0 20px 15px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

/* GRID ELEMENTS */

/* Global CSS*/
 .row > div{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .content{
        background: #b4bac0;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
    /* When there is 2 columns on top of eachother */
    .sidebar{
        background: #b4bac0;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
    .sidebar-top{
        min-height: 140px;
        background: #dbdfe7;
    }
    .sidebar-bottom{
        min-height: 145px;
        background: #7e8aa0;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
    }
 /* Padding used for the core CSS */
 .small-padding.top {
    padding-top:5px;
 }

 .small-padding.bottom {
     padding-bottom:5px;
 } 
 .small-padding.left {
     padding-left:7.5px;
 }

 .small-padding.right {
     padding-right:7.5px;
 }

 button {
  float-right
 }
 /* Media quries */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    margin-left: -7.5px;
    margin-right: -7.5px;
  }

  .row>[class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
  }

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>GRID PANEL MERGE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
 <div class="index-content">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
           <div class="card">
              <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
              </div>
        </div>
         </div>
   </a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="index-content">
 <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
              <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
            </div>
   </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="card">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
              
              <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
            </div>
   </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want. But in cases like this I like to use flexbox.

I added a small flexbox container in your code.

```css
.index-content a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.index-content {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /*padding: 50px 0px;*/
}

.index-content .row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.index-content a {
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.index-content .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.index-content .card h4 {
  margin: 20px;
}

.index-content .card p {
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.index-content .blue-button {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: #002E5B;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.index-content .blue-button:hover {
  background-color: #dadada;
  color: #002E5B;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .index-content .col-lg-4 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
/* Card < 768px */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    position: relative;
  }
  .card-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .card-content h4,
  .card-content p {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
  }
  .card-content a {
    float: right;
  }
  .index-content .card h4,
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 0 20px 15px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

/* GRID ELEMENTS */

/* Global CSS*/
 .row > div{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .content{
        background: #b4bac0;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
    /* When there is 2 columns on top of eachother */
    .sidebar{
        background: #b4bac0;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
    .sidebar-top{
        min-height: 140px;
        background: #dbdfe7;
    }
    .sidebar-bottom{
        min-height: 145px;
        background: #7e8aa0;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
    }
 /* Padding used for the core CSS */
 .small-padding.top {
    padding-top:5px;
 }

 .small-padding.bottom {
     padding-bottom:5px;
 } 
 .small-padding.left {
     padding-left:7.5px;
 }

 .small-padding.right {
     padding-right:7.5px;
 }

 /* Media quries */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    margin-left: -7.5px;
    margin-right: -7.5px;
  }

  .row>[class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
        }
        
        .flex-container {
            flex-direction:column;
        }
        .card-container {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

    }
    
    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
    }
    .card-container {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>GRID PANEL MERGE</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="index-content">
              <div class="container">
                <a href="#">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card">
                              <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg">
                              <div class="card-content">
                                <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </a>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="index-content">
            <div class="container">
                
                        <div class="flex-container">
                            <div class="card-container">
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg">
                                            <div class="card-content">
                                                <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                                                <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-container">
                                <div class="card">
                                        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg">
                                        <div class="card-content">
                                          <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                                          
                                          <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                                        </div>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</body>
</html>
```